# Content Moves to the right when browser is in full screen (CSS)

Tags: css

I'm working on CountryGardensNursery.co and everything shows up just fine in Firefox.  When I cross check in Safari and Chrome in full screen, the content on the pages moves to the right of the page instead of the center.

I have the content in two containers:

```
<div class="main_container"><div class="page_container"></div></div>
```

The CSS related to the code is:

```
.main_container {
    width: 1000px;
    background: transparent;
    margin: 0 auto -30px;
    top: -30px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 90;
}

.page_container {
    background: transparent;
    width: 700px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 20px 10px 0px;
    min-height: 500px;
}
```

I'm coding this site on Wordpress.  Is there a line of code or does anyone see any kind of conflict?  Any help would be great!  Thanks.

Page with conflict: [www.countrygardensnursery.co/about/](http://www.countrygardensnursery.co/about/)

Comment: could you setup a fiddle or point us to the page (if it's hosted)?

Comment: just added the link.  sorry about that.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything but centered content in either Chrome or Safari via Windows 7, has the problem been fixed?

Comment: Yes, just got it fix.  Thank you for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<header>` is not containing it's overflow. Use one of the following solutions:

**Overflow**

```
header { /* style.css:1481 */
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Clearfix** - Recommended

```
header:after { /* style.css:1481 */
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  something so simple that I left out.  That worked perfectly!